# How do I find out what errors a tcl command can generate?

Tags: error-handling, tcl

At the [tcl try manpage](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm), it has the following example:

```
try {
    set f [open /some/file/name w]
} trap {POSIX EISDIR} {} {
    puts "failed to open /some/file/name: it's a directory"
} trap {POSIX ENOENT} {} {
    puts "failed to open /some/file/name: it doesn't exist"
}
```

That's great, it works, but how would I have found out that `{POSIX ENOENT}` is a possible trap pattern for `open`? The [open manpage](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm) doesn't mention it. For a given arbitrary command in tcl, how do I find out what the possible errors are?

Comment: “Some API documentation, from somewhere” - unfortunately, may be under documented or ‘rely on knowledge of lower-level system call erros’. In this specific case, the C/system man pages would be relevant.

Comment: @user2864740 So this try feature is basically undocumented then. Fabulous. Better to avoid this entirely than to trap a couple errors, thinking you've got them all and then have your app crash.

Comment: That's a tad on the negative tone, is it not? You can use `trap {}` or `on error` to trap any *other* errors that were not trapped by previous `trap` and that's documented on the manual page. Under-documented != undocumented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various `POSIX` errors come from the OS, and you need to take a guess at the system call and look them up. For example, it's not a great reach to guess that the `open` command maps to the [`open()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), and so it has the errors documented there. Some are vastly unlikely with Tcl (e.g., those relating to passing a bad buffer in, which is `POSIX EFAULT`) but we don't guarantee that the OS won't return them because the OS simply doesn't give that guarantee to us.

We ought to document the most likely ones from commands that touch the operating system, but at a high level:

- the `POSIX` class ones are from the OS (e.g., reading a non-existent file is `POSIX ENOENT`), and
- the `TCL` class ones are from Tcl's own internal code (e.g., from passing the wrong number of arguments to `open`, which gives you `TCL WRONGARGS`, or asking for too large a memory allocation, which gives you `TCL MEMORY` if Tcl manages to recover).

We're unlikely to exhaustively document all the possibilities (especially in the `TCL` class) since many are unlikely in correct code.

Answer (score 3):

`try {} trap {}` is used when there is a specific error that needs to be trapped.
For a more general trap, use `try {} on error {}`.

```
try {
   set fh [open myfile.txt w]
} on error {err res} {
   puts "Error on open: $res"
}
```

There is also the catch command:

```
if { [catch {set fh [open myfile.txt w]}] } {
   puts "error on open."
}
```

References: [try](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)  [catch](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to find that no one had mentioned how to list POSIX errors on *NIX systems (not guaranteeing this for *all* *NIX but it did work on the few I tried).

To answer your (extended) question:
*how do I find out what the possible errors are (from the operating system)?*

```
errno --search file
```

The short option form is `-s`

You can see all POSIX errors with:

```
errno --list
```

The short option form is `-ls`, (or even `-l`)

Output lines are of the form:

```
ERRNAME errcode error message
```

Examples:

```
ENOENT 2 No such file or directory
EISDIR 21 Is a directory
```